# Is there a way to transfer my ETH from a cold storage to a hot storage without compromising it?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, cold-storage, myetherwallet

At first I wanted to use myetherwallet.com but now I am afraid the code may be hacked / corrupted some day.

The cold storage solution seems safer to store ETH in the long run.

While I understand how I can send ETH from a hot storage to a cold storage, I don't get how I could then transfer back my ETH to sell it for example, without compromising my cold storage by writing down my unencrypted key or my combo encrypted key + password on a computer connected to the internet.

Is there any way to do it or is there another way to securely store ETH?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we can now do it directly with myetherwallet.com, in the Advanced (offline) transaction tabs.

To make it secure just follow the process with one part on the online computer and the other on the offline computer

Answer (score 2):

[Icebox](https://github.com/ConsenSys/icebox) is a light-wallet that allows you to create a wallet offline using a static HTML page.

You just write down the seed on a piece of paper, and store it. When you want to send Ether, you can use Icebox to sign a transaction offline, then move the signed transaction data to an online computer and use `eth.sendRawTransaction` to post the transaction to the network.

Answer (score 1):

Christian Lundkvist / ConenSys's [Icebox](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/431fns/introducing_icebox_a_cold_storage_ether_wallet/) was specifically made for long-term, offline storage and gives you the ability to sign transactions offline.

However, you can [download the repo](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet) for MyEtherWallet.com and run it locally as well, if you are worried about code being corrupted or the site going offline in the future.

[This thread from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/477htl/chain_for_ethereum/) also lists a myriad of ways of signing transactions offline, which is what it sounds like you want to do.